# How to remove duplicate values from the list in python with out using any predefined variable

Tags: python, list

I am trying to remove duplicate values from a list.

This is what i have so far:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,3,2,1]
list2=[]
l=len(list1)

for i in range(l):
    if list1[i] not in list2:
         list2.append(list1[i])

print(list2)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And it works just fine.

However, i am wondering if you can get the same result under the following conditions:

**Conditions:**

- Should not use any predefined functions to remove item
- Can use loops but, only once
- And should not use any other 2nd list

I tried but I didn't make any progress. Is it possible..?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Please show us your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "should not use any other 2nd list"? Can you use the original list and the resulting list, which is two lists total?

Comment: Voting to close as this question does not contain the attempt made by the asker and the artificial constraints are vaguely defined.

Comment: `list1=[1,2,3,4,3,2,1]`
`list2=[]`
`l=len(list1)`
`for i in range(l):`
 `if list1[i] not in list2:`
  `list2.append(list1[i])`
`print(list2)` 
First i shown this to him then he added the 3rd condition to do not use any other list

Comment: please read your own question carefully...you are using two list..

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `set`.  A `set` is technically a type.  Technically correct is the best kind of correct.

```
>>> type(set)
<class 'type'>
>>> set([1,1,1,1,1,1,2])
{1, 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this follow the *sadistic* rules?

```
alist = [1,2,3,4,1,1,6,7,2,2,8,10]

i = 0
while i < len(alist):
    if alist[i] in alist[i+1:]:
        del alist[i]
        i -= 1
    i += 1
print(alist)
#[3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 2, 8, 10]
```

The order of the items in the list returned might seem weird but what actually happens is that the last appearance of every item is kept.

However, i would not recommend you to spend too much time with my code. Playing with `i` like this is not adviceable and the solutions (which might not satisfy your rules) using `list(set(alist))` are of course better.

Comment: `remove` is a function. This may or may not actually matter, but as OP's question stands, this would not be correct.

Comment: You can `del alist[i]`, and I'm pretty sure that would work.

Comment: Thanks, that one slipped. `len()` is a function too though.. So, just say to your professor that you did solve it but you cannot show him the result because `print()` is a function.

Comment: FWIW, you can eliminate that `len` call by appending a sentinel object to the end of the list before you loop over it (and delete it at the end), eg `class Sentinel: pass`. And use Python 2 so you can use the `print` statement. :)